# Android Service onStart vs onCreate

Tags: android, service

What is the difference in a Service between onStart and onCreate?
Where should I write my code to initialize the service?

I am a bit confused about this.

Comment: write your code in onstart..and for difference pls read android developer.

Answer (score -1):

onResume() is called always the user retuns to the activity, but if the procces is not killed the method onCreate() is not called.
onCreate() is called when the proccess app is killed (for example to libery memory) and the user returns to activity.

Here a scheme:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: The question is about a Service not Activity.